What is the idiomatic Rust alternate to an irrefutable if let?
Clippy is warning that the following 'if let' in push_char() is irrefutable, thus useless, and recommends replacing the 'if let' with 'let'.  What is the idiomatic rust way to address this warning?
#[derive(Clone, Debug, PartialEq)]
pub enum StrComponent {
    Word(String),
    Other(String),
}

impl StrComponent {
    pub fn push_char(&mut self, c: char) {
        if let StrComponent::Other(s) | StrComponent::Word(s) = self {
            s.push(c);
        }
    }
}


Per Clippy's feedback, I've tried replacing 'if let' with 'let' but that results in a compiler error.  I've also Googled alternate ways of access the data within an enum variant, but 'if let' or match patterns dominate.
Strictly replacing 'if let' with 'let'
    pub fn push_char(&mut self, c: char) {
        let StrComponent::Other(s) | StrComponent::Word(s) = self {
            s.push(c);
        }
    }

results in
32 |         let StrComponent::Other(s) | StrComponent::Word(s) = self {
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: wrap the pattern in parentheses: `(StrComponent::Other(s) | StrComponent::Word(s))

Adding parentheses
    pub fn push_char(&mut self, c: char) {
        let (StrComponent::Other(s) | StrComponent::Word(s)) = self {
            s.push(c);
        }
    }

results in
32 |         let (StrComponent::Other(s) | StrComponent::Word(s)) = self {
   |                                                                ---- while parsing this struct
33 |             s.push(c);
   |             -^ expected one of `,`, `:`, or `}`
   |             |
   |             while parsing this struct field
   |
help: try naming a field

I've tried the next couple recommended steps, e.g., naming field and the code doesn't seem to be converging on something valid.
Any recommendations?  At the end of the day, I'd like to get access to and modify the string within StrComponent variants Word and Other.

Plain let, follow the "help: wrap the pattern in parentheses:" let (A(s) | B(s)) = self;

let doesn't take a block {} you must end it with a semicolon ; You can read the correct syntax in my previous comment and the linked question.

What this error means is that the successful branch of the if will always be taken, so rather than write this as an if, you'd rather write unconditional code.

Thanks for the help, @cafce25.  As one just going through the rust book chapter 6, that wasn't very obvious.

I'm just a little baffled why you'd think it is supported, given that chapter 2 introduces let and it's syntax is always let pattern = expr;. Granted the error message on your parenthesized attempt isn't too great, but that's because the resulting invalid code is ambiguous and thus it's impossible to tell what it should really mean from the compilers perspective.
